# Best way to communicate Raspberry Pi and ATTiny13

Tags: avr, spi, i2c, raspberry-pi, attiny

What is best way to connect two or three microcontrollers, ATTiny13 to Raspberry-Pi and get master (Raspberry Pi) communication? Are there any ready libraries for ATTiny13 for SPI or I2C? Maybe some other protocol supported by Raspberry Pi?

It doesn't have to be really fast. 1-wire speed is enough for me. Easiness is priority for me but I also don't want buy too many expensive items.

I found 1-wire slave library but I have issues with it so I'm looking for alternative.

Comment: Best how? Easiest? Cheapest? Fastest?

Comment: It don't have to be really fast. 1-wire speed is enough for me.  Easiness is priority for me but I also don't want buy too many expensive items.

Comment: What sort of issues are you facing, why do you need an alternative?

Comment: It looks like size of code generated by avr-gcc is too big for ATTiny13 (about 2KB).

Comment: SPI slave-mode should be really simple to implement in software by using a pin-change interrupt for the CLK line; master-mode may even be easier. I2C or 1-wire are probably much more complex to implement w.r.t. code size, RAM usage, and computation time.

Comment: What about serial/USB serial?  Or did I miss something?

Comment: I understand that the OP is talking about one-to-many communication, which will need additional effort when realized via RS232.

Comment: Yes, it will be one-to-many. But I think that I will do some experiments with RS232.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard I2C or SPI. Master implementations exist for Raspberry Pi, and slave implementations exist for AVR. Using TinyAVR seriously limits usage for a very basic processing, so maybe you should opt for AVR with more memory if that becomes the problem. You can also use RS485 single master multi slaves serial communication over Pi's RS232 if RS485 interface chips are used on Pi and all AVRs. Of course, in this case you must implement some known standard protocol or create your own custom protocol.

Comment: You don't actually need interface chips to implement an RS485 style protocol over short distances, as both devices are capable of tri-stating their serial transmit pins to allow others to talk.